# Is there any way to write this number with these limits?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Is there any way to write this number:

$$ \frac{17+15\sqrt{5}}{7+15\sqrt{5}} $$

Just using the digits $1$, $4$, $7$, $8$, $9$ once each with the following criteria:

- A maximum of two square root signs ($\sqrt{}$).
- Unlimited use of $+$, $-$, $*$ and $/$.
- Unlimited use of parentheses.
- No exponentiation.
- No decimal sign.

Comment: Do you get to use each digit as many times as you like, or once each?

Comment: Probably once each; otherwise this is too easy: just break everything down into a bunch of ones.

Comment: Damn it, forgot to say once each...

Answer (score 2):

What about

$$\frac{(9+8)+(8+7)\sqrt{4+1}}{7+(8+7)\sqrt{4+1}}\;\;\;?$$

Comment: It may be that we're only allowed to use each digit once.

Comment: It may, it could, it would: the above represents what the OP asked for with his own conditions. What he may have meant is for magicians and thoughts-guessers to know.

Comment: And hence why vadim asked for clarification.

Comment: Save yourself an addition sign and just concatenate 1 and 7 to get 17 ;p

Comment: Yes, that's true:  only two commenters and I mixed them. Shall delete my comments here to avoid noise.